# Restart Shiny Session

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

This seems like a very obvious question but I haven't found anything on the subject.

How can I refresh a shiny application (the equivalent of pressing F5, or clicking the "Reload App" button in RStudio)?

ui.R

```
 shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("goButton", "Refresh")
  ),  
  mainPanel(
        h4("I would really like to refresh this please.")
    )   
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 
  observe({
    if(input$goButton==0) return(NULL)
    isolate({
      #
      #  I would like to refresh my session here with some sort of 
      #  function like session(refresh)...
    })
    })
})
```

I don't think I want to use stopApp() - I just want to refresh it such that it's in the same state as when it is loaded.

**UPDATE**

On the RStudio website, it shows [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532327-Managing-the-Server) how to manage a user's session from the server.  Specifically,

```
$ sudo rstudio-server suspend-session <pid>
```

Is there the equivalent function as the user, from within the app? In the documentation for session info ([here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html)), it says there is an onSessionEnded(callback) function.  It would be good if there was a session.End() function which performs the above suspend-session function!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `history.go(0)` js-method to reload the page and thus reset the session, e.g. from a link:

```
p(HTML("<A HREF=\"javascript:history.go(0)\">Reset this page</A>"))
```

Furthermore you can use the [`shinyjs` package](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/) to execute javascript from within the server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}" # Define the js method that resets the page

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),                                           # Include shinyjs in the UI
    extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode, functions = "reset"), # Add the js code to the page
    actionButton("reset_button", "Reset Page")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$reset_button, {js$reset()})          # Call the method from
                                                            # somewhere within the server
  })
```

Comment: Nice answer @bubble. As the author of shinyjs, I'd also like to add that if resetting all the inputs is sufficient (ie. get all the input values back to their initial state, instead of literally refreshing the page), then you can use the built-in shinyjs reset function

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @daattali :) It was my first answer.

Comment: Nice answer, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 23):

The session has now a method to do the trick. Shinyjs is no longer required:

```
session$reload()
```

Comment: Which requires adding `session` to the server's `function()` arguments.

Comment: If I have a shinydashboard with multiple tibItems and I would like to refresh a specific tabItem without leave this TabItem panel?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. There are several questions about such scenarios here at SO. If none of those answer your question, you can ask your own one. Without further details my first thought would be to put all tab content in a `uiOutput` element and get the content from the server with `renderUI`.

Answer (score 9):

You can add a refresh icon and popover to your app by including the following in your ui code:

```
library(shinyBS)

tags$a(href="javascript:history.go(0)", 
           popify(tags$i(class="fa fa-refresh fa-5x"),
                  title = "Reload", 
                  content = "Click here to restart the Shiny session",
                  placement = "right"))
```

It should give you this:

[image]