# Why does observeEvent don't re-evaluate it's content?

Tags: r, shiny

In the following example, the text is not shown in the start. If I click on the "show"-Button the text appears. If I then click on the "hide"-Button nothing else happens anymore.
In fact the "textis$visible" variable has always the correct value, but i think the if-statement in the observeEvent funktion is only calculated after the very first button click.

Is there a way to force observeEvent to re-evaluate the if statement? Or are there other ways to stop shiny from executing code in the server part and restart it again (in the real case there would be a whole bunch of function calls inside the if statement, not just hide and show some text)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

actionButton(inputId="show","show"),
actionButton(inputId="hide","hide"),

textOutput(outputId = "some_text")
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  textis<-reactiveValues(visible=FALSE)

observeEvent(input$show,
             textis$visible<-TRUE)

observeEvent(input$hide,
             textis$visible<-FALSE)

observeEvent(textis$visible  , if(textis$visible){
  output$some_text<-renderText({"this is some text"})  
})}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observeEvent expressions are evaluated any time the value of their event expression changes. But, in the code you have above, when `textis$visible` changes, the observer only has instructions to perform if `textis$visible` is true. In the code snippet below, I've used `else{...}` to give that observer an action to perform when `testis$visible` is not true.

```
  observeEvent(textis$visible  , if(textis$visible){
    output$some_text<-renderText({"this is some text"})  
  } else {output$some_text<-renderText({''}) }
  )}
```

So, if you paste the else clause above into your app, the output some_text will disappear when the hide button is clicked.

Comment: This kind of solves my problem. But in the real application I want to stop server.R from executing a part of it's code and don't show the already executed stuff if a certain value becomes false. It is like a log out function, that other computer users don't see what you have calculated. Is there maybe a way to restart a R session?

Comment: for the reset of the shiny app i found a good answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062422/restart-shiny-session

Answer (score 2):

It is not very good practice to put a render element in an observer (and it is unnecessary). Also since you have only one reactiveValue, you could use `reactiveVal()`, see the example below. You can call its value with `text_visible()`, and update it with `text_visible(new_value)`.

Working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton(inputId="show","show"),
  actionButton(inputId="hide","hide"), 
  textOutput(outputId = "some_text")
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  text_visible<-reactiveVal(TRUE)

  observeEvent(input$show,
               text_visible(TRUE))

  observeEvent(input$hide,
               text_visible(FALSE))

  output$some_text<-renderText({ 
    if(text_visible()) 
      return("this is some text")
    else
      return("")
  })
}

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton(inputId="show","show"),
  actionButton(inputId="hide","hide"),
  textOutput(outputId = "some_text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  textis <- reactiveVal(F)
  observeEvent(input$show,{textis(T)})

  observeEvent(input$hide,{textis(F)})

  result <- eventReactive(textis(),{
    if(!textis()){
      return()
    }
    "this is some text"
  })

  output$some_text<-renderText({result()}) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```